# Blank Span Element Not Visible

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I have following span element in my html

```
<span style="float: right;color: red; display: inline-block;" id="antcl_error"></span>
```

But When i checked its visibility then it says not Visible

```
$(document.body).find("#antcl_error").is(":visible");
```

Above code return false if Span is blank

Comment: What's the problem? That's part of the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

Comment: @4castle Why it is giving false while my span element is visible on screen

Comment: Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document. Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero.

Comment: Are you sure it's visible on screen? It considers elements with 0 width or 0 height as invisible.

Comment: okay but then how to check empty element's visibility

Comment: How do you define visible? Do you mean `visibility:hidden` or `display:none`?

Comment: if Elements' s parent container is visible on screen and user doing some interaction with that element then this span should return **True**

Comment: to understand difference between `visibility:hidden` or `display:none` , see this http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blfaqhidden.htm

Comment: @yash I know that ..please read my previous comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the span is floated and has no content and no width and height, it does not consume space in the document, hence it is considered invisible:

You can check for the visibility value of CSS:

```
if($("#antcl_error").css('visibility') != "hidden") {
   // visible
}
```

As per documentation:

> Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document.
>   Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero.
>
> Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered visible,
>   since they still consume space in the layout.

Answer (score 1):

Check if css display mode is not none:

```js
if($('body').find("#antcl_error").css('display') != "none") {
   alert('visible')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span style="float: right;color: red; display:inline-block;" id="antcl_error"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained on a previous thread:
[WordPress removes empty span tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44261039/wordpress-removes-empty-span-tag/68180066#68180066)

You can set styling elements to an empty span block using general css and place a 
 tag within the span. Then within your css stylesheet apply a display:none; to the 
 tag within the span to remove the unwanted space whilst retaining the  styling elements and for it to still be displayed. (this depends on your theme structure)